# Unity Interface select on Click in Scene View

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity won't let me select objects on my scene without first selecting the object in the Hierarchy. [This](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-select-objects-with-mouse-click-in-unity-5-2.353755/) was all I could find on the issue.

However, it seems that they decided that closing and opening the scene window fixed the bug, but not so with me. Also note that I am on a blank project. Its been really difficult to work around this bug.

Edit:
I have even uninstalled Unity and reinstalled with the hopes that this would solve the problem, but unfortunately it did not. Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Honestly this is such an odd problem that I'm having difficulty knowing how to try and fix the problem. I also reported the bug as recommended below by NoëlWidmer, but even the staff who was very kind had no idea how to deal with the problem, and the advice he gave also didn't change a thing. Truly, I don't even know what more information I can give you guys because as I said I literally opened a new Unity project for the first time after reinstalling and was unable to select without first clicking on the hierarchy. Is this just a special freak case that landed with me or has this happened to anyone else?? Also I'm using a two year old Windows 8 Laptop with literally nothing installed on it but the Adobe suite and a few other game developer necessities, so my computer most likely is not the source of the problem.

Edit: a Clue??
Well I was messing around with the scene and hierarchy view in full screen, and I noticed something interesting after clicking on the object in the hierarchy and moving the object in the scene view:
[image]
Unfortunately my PrintScreen doesnt show the actual mouse, but as you can see the scene view acts as though I'm clicking on the object, but here at the same time I saw my real mouse off down to the right! Also while I've selected an object on the scene editor and I move my mouse off the scene window things get a bit off and the mouse will pop up on other sides of the window and so on. I don't know if that's normal and its that way for everyone or if it's just me and it might help figure out what's going on.

Man I've really been liking Unity but if this keeps up I think I'll have to drop it and find another software, because I certainly will never be able to design anything worth while if I have to select the object on the hierarchy every time for every single object.

Comment: You may want to report as Karl Jones wrote: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting

Comment: do you have a PC, Mac or what ?  what target ?

Comment: @NoëlWidmer Alright. I just reported the bug.

Comment: @Programmer Version 5.3.4

Comment: @JoeBlow PC, the bug (if it is a bug which I'm pretty sure it is) occurs in all my projects

Comment: Try Unity 5.4 http://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: @DrakeSwartzy Did you even try the latest version I linked here?

Comment: @Programmer yes unfortunately that didn't change the problem either oddly enough, but it was a great suggestion and I have no idea why these changes aren't working

Comment: For posterity: I just had this same issue with Unity UI and I realized it was because my gizmos were disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm overwhelmed with joy right now!! The problem was indeed a bug. I was working on a project and moving objects around (still using the hierarchy to select objects) and then a split second later for absolutely no reason Unity decided to start working the way it should've!!! I guess its just one of those issues where you just have to cross your fingers and hope it'll resolve itself. I'm so glad this dumb issue resolved itself because I was about to tear my hair out and succumb to using another computer for my unity design, or even worse another software. Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 3):

Some bug for me on Mac platform. I resolve just entering and exit from fullscreen mode.

Probably may also work change layout with top-right combo.

Comment: Full screen mode for what exactly? And how do you turn this mode on and off? And unfortunately changing the layout didn't fix the problem.

Comment: On osX Mac editor version, on the right we have a green button to switch between full screen/window mode. Try also closing the scene view (right mouse button on title) and then reopen it (menu window\scene)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using PC, and I'm not finding this button. Also I've been trying the scene close over and over again to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while using older versions of unity (in addition inspector window lost the focus repeatedly). In my case rearraging editor windows and saving custom window layout solved it. As far as I remember, I just moved scene view outside Unity window (on the second screen) as well as hierarchy view, and saved resulting position as a new window layout.
Not sure if there is anything else I can tell about it, it's pretty mysterious problem.

Comment: I was really hoping that this would solve it once and for all but after messing around with the window layout and trying all kinds of things there was no change. I'm glad I'm not the only one who's had this bizarre problem though